# Запятая перед "или". Как правильно?

Tags: запятые, или

1. Делай честный выбор, или умри.
2. Делай честный выбор или умри.

Какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Делай честный выбор, или умри.***

Вот как здесь решить эту задачу (сделать выбор)?

1) **Розенталь! Н**о увы, нет у Розенталя подходящего правила.

2)Это ССП (сложносочиненное предложение)? Тогда запятую надо ставить.

3) Но простые предложения не двусоставные, а **односоставные** определенно-личные. Иногда их приравнивают к однородным членам.

**Но вот как раз про них-то ничего не сказано у Розенталя.** Нет у них общей побудительной частицы, нет общей вопросительной или восклицательной интонации.

4) Может быть, всё-таки можно **приравнять их к однородным членам?**
Это, конечно, вариант, но здесь нужна **однородность,** а как ее вычислить?

5) Составим такое предложение: ***Делай свою работу хорошо или не делай ее вообще.***

Да, здесь запятая, скорее всего, не ставится, так как ситуации вполне себе однородные и тогда сказуемые однородные тоже.

6) А теперь: ***Делай честный выбор, или умри.***

Да уж, это уже не выбор, а нечто другое. Определяем эти ситуации **как неоднородные** и запятую ставим (в сложном предложении).